# Потеря сессии Java-приложения

Tags: java, сессия, jsp

В JSP файле имеется форма form. Помимо основных полей ввода и ссылок с `JavaScript:sendForm('${data})` имеется ссылка-тег `<a>`, из которой вызывается функция JavaScript `gotoDescription()` для перехода на информационную html страницу -  не action:

```
function gotoDescription(name){
var file = "Info/"+name+".html";
location.href('description.jsp?file='+file);
}
```

Однако при отработке по данной функции происходит потеря сессии Java-приложения.
Что не так, почему теряется сессия, как по-иному реализовать задуманное?

Answer (score 2):

Надо добавить в ваш урл параметры JSP сессии:

```
var encodedUrl = '<%= response.encodeURL(url)%>';
location.href(encodedUrl);
```